# Test rest service having RequestParam using postman

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, postman

I want to test my REST service in order to save a product having a certain category (manyToOne) with Postman:

This is the body of my request:

```
{
    "categoryId": 36,
    "product": {
        "code": "code1",
        "name": "product1",
        "price": 20
    }
}
```

And this is how the signature of my REST service method looks like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addProduct", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<ProductBean> add(@RequestParam(value ="categoryId") Long id, @RequestParam(value = "product") ProductBean productBean)
```

I put in Postman my URL with the `/addProduct` at the end, then I choose `POST`. In the body tab, I choose `raw` and select the `JSON (application json)`.
When I send the request I got HTTP 400.

How can test this without error in Postman?

**Edit**

I want to test it using postman to be sure that my REST is working before adding the front part. This is how I will send the data from the front

```
add: function (product, id, successCallBack, failureCallBack) {
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: "/addProduct",
            params: {
                product: product,
                categoryId: id
            },
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        }).then(successCallBack, failureCallBack);
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your method signature is incorrect. @RequestParam is the parameter in the uri, not the body of the request. It should be:

```
 public ResponseEntity<ProductBean> add(MyBean myBean)
```

where  `MyBean` has to properties: id and product or

```
public ResponseEntity<ProductBean> add(@ModelAttribute(value ="categoryId") Long id, @ModelAttribute(value = "product") ProductBean productBean)
```

For more on mapping requests see [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-requestmapping)

If you want to stick to your original mapping, then everything should be passed in the query string and nothing in the body. 
The query string will look something like that:

```
/addProduction?categoryId=36&product={"code":"code1",...}
```

Comment: What if I want to test it using RequestParam? How can I do that?

Comment: See my edit, but you should really consider to pass data from ui in the body of the request and use `data` instead of `params`